# Calculating the best route with different start and end locations

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-directions-api

In my app users can choose a number of destinations in a city they would like to visit.

At the moment I'm using this to determine the best route beween LocationA and LocationD whilst making sure to go to the best route taking in LocationB and LocationC https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints

At the moment LocationA is fixed to the origin and LocationD is fixed to the destination in the directionService.route part of this

I want to check if there is a better route than going from LocationA to LocationD. Maybe LocationD to LocationC is faster taking in LocationA and LocationB on the way.

Is there a way to do this without fixing the start and end of the journey?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, doesn't seems to have a Google solution for this.(not sure).

But there is a way to solve: create a function that receives a list of locations, set they as origin and destination, the rest as waypoints, then get all the distances and calculate the better. something like:

```
Route getBetterRoute(Location[] list)

    Route betterRoute;

    for( int x = 0; x < list.size; x++)
        for( int y = 0; y < list.size; y++)
            Location origin = list[x];
            Location destination = list[y];
            Location[] waypoints = list[] - origin - destination;
            Route routeXY = RequestOptmizedRoute(origin, destination, waypoints);

            if( betterRoute ==  null ) 
                betterRoute = routeXy;
            if( routeXY.distance() < betterRoute.distance() ) 
                betterRoute = routeXY;

return betterRoute
```

If you are doing this in mobile, it's better to create a backend function.